# Set z-index for edge labels in VisJS

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am working on a layout in VisJS that involves a lot of nodes. When edges are hovered over, I have text that I want to appear and then hide on leave.

When the nodes are crowded and the edge labels run into it, they are currently displaying so that they are underneath the nodes, instead of above. Is there any way I can set the z-index of the edge label so that they appear on top of the nodes rather than underneath them?

I have read the docs extensively and haven't seen anything that would be likely to change the position in the z index. any hacks or workaround would be welcomed. Thanks!

working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4e02d7z/1/)

My visjs code:

```js
const root = document.querySelector('#graph');

const nodeData = [
    {
    type: "A",
    name: 'A Node 1',
    index: 0,
    x: -50,
    y: -50
  },
  {
    type: 'A',
    name: 'A node 2',
    index: 1,
    x: -50,
    y: 50
  },
  {
    type: 'A',
    name: 'A node 3',
    index: 2,
    x: -150,
    y: 50
  },
  {
    type: 'A',
    name: 'A Node 4',
    index: 3,
    x: 50,
    y: 50
  },
  {
    type: 'A',
    name: 'A Node 5',
    index: 4,
    x: -50,
    y: 150
  },
  {
    type: "B",
    name: 'B Node 1',
    index: 5
  },
  {
    type: "B",
    name: 'B Node 2',
    index: 6
  },
  {
    type: 'B',
    name: 'B Node ',
    index: 7
  },
    {
    type: 'B',
    name: 'B Node ',
    index: 8
  },
      {
    type: 'B',
    name: 'B Node ',
    index: 9
  },
      {
    type: 'B',
    name: 'B Node ',
    index: 10
  },
      {
    type: 'B',
    name: 'B Node ',
    index: 11
  },
      {
    type: 'B',
    name: 'B Node ',
    index: 12
  },    {
    type: 'B',
    name: 'B Node ',
    index: 13
  },
];

const edgeData = [
    {from: 0, to: 1},
  {from: 1, to: 2},
  {from: 1, to: 3},
  {from: 1, to: 4},
  {from: 2, to: 5},
  {from: 3, to: 6},
  {from: 4, to: 7},
  {from: 4, to: 8},
  {from: 4, to: 9},
  {from: 4, to: 10},
  {from: 4, to: 11},
  {from: 4, to: 12},
  {from: 4, to: 13},
]

const options = {
    physics: {
      barnesHut: {
        avoidOverlap: 1,
        springConstant: 0.3
      },
      solver: 'hierarchicalRepulsion'
    },
  layout: {
    randomSeed: '0:0'
  }
};

const nodes = new vis.DataSet(nodeData.map(d => {
    const newNode = {
    id: d.index,
    label: d.name,
    fixed: d.type === 'A'
  }
  if (typeof d.x === 'number') {
    newNode.x = d.x;
  }
  
  if (typeof d.y === 'number') {
    newNode.y = d.y;
  }
  
  if(d.type === 'A') {
    newNode.color = 'orange';
    newNode.mass = 3;
  }
  return newNode;
}));
const edges = new vis.DataSet(edgeData.map(e => {
    return {...e, smooth: false, label: 'edge from node to node'}
}));
const network = new vis.Network(root, {nodes, edges}, options);

network.on('stabilizationIterationsDone', () => network.setOptions({physics: false}));
```